# Медленный отклик OnClick() в RecycleView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-on-click, setonclicklistener

В `RecycleView` загружаю 10.000 строк.
Прокрутка плавная, без проблем.
В каждый строке есть `imageview`, но `onClick` выполняется с задержкой (при 50 записей норм):

```
vh.iv.setOnClickListener {
            when (isFavorite(item.id)) {
                false -> {
                    cipher.execSQL("update table set exam=\'1\' where id=\'${item.id}\'")
                    context.rateColor(vh.imgFavorite, true)
                    list[position].favorite = "1"
                }
                true -> {
                    cipher.execSQL("update table set exam=\'0\' where id=\'${item.id}\'")
                    context.rateColor(vh.imgFavorite, false)
                    list[position].favorite = "0"
                }
            }
    }
```

Как оптимизировать, чтоб без задержки работало?

Comment: Возможно это запрос в БД медленно работает. Попробуйте его убрать. Если поможет-выносите в другой поток запрос

Comment: Что именно выполняется с задержкой? Точно OnClickListener? Попробуйте залогировать время в миллисекундах перед `when (isFavorite(item.id)) {`и в самом конце метода, может, потеря времени в одной из вызываемых операций?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Добавлять в RecyclerView более 30-50 элементов - издевательство для телефона, специально для вас придумали Paging Library

Answer (score 0):

Вы выполняете запрос в Базу Данных на UI потоке. Естественно это не быстрая операция и она тормозит ваш UI поток. В зависимости от ваших потребностей у вас в целом есть 2 варинта.

1. Это сделать запрос в рабочем потоке а действие по клику на UI потоке. Так ваш  UI отреагирует быстро, а запрос сделается уже невидимо для пользователя. Этот вариант подойдет в случае если вам не важен результат от запроса или вы можете его обработать независимо от того что будет в данный момент на экране.
2. Это все равно выносить запрос в рабочий поток (так вы не будете грузить UI и пользователь сможет дальше с ним взаимодействовать). И пока выполняется запрос показать какой-то лоадер на весь экран или же на конкретный элемент, тут уже от ваших задач зависит. По окончанию запроса выполнить действие в зависимости от результата. Чаще второй вариант предпочтительнее, но все зависит от задач.